# Putting excel cell value into a character array

Tags: arrays, excel, type-conversion, excel-2013, vba

I need to dump a cell's content into a character array so that I can loop through and remove undesired characters. (ie. I want to convert "00d" to "00") I know how to remove the character, however I am having trouble getting the cell into the array. Below is my latest attempt.

```
Dim content() As Characters
Dim convert As String
For Each cell In .Range("J2:" & .Range("J2").End(xlDown).Address)
    convert = .Cells(cell.Row, 10)
    content = convert.tochararray()
    For i = LBound(content) To UBound(content)
        If content(i) = "d" Then
            content(i) = ""
        End If
    Next
Next
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should look into regex.replace.